# mysql query to fetch sum of km travelled by a vehicle multiple times in a day without entering date

Tags: mysql

I have tried this query but
not getting the output
SELECT sum(traveledDistanceInKm) actualDistanceInKm -sum(traveledDistanceInKm) from tracking_details

Comment: My guess is you are looking for aggregation using GROUP_BY

Comment: `n - n = 0` which is probably not what you want. You haven't explained what you *do* want. Please have a read of [How to ask a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)

Comment: Yes I am looking aggregation, but my question is A vehicle traveled some xx(ex 50 km) km out of xxx km(500km) in whole day, but its updated many times in a day(ex 4 times), I want to add those sum of km traveled by a vehicle in a day(first day)

Answer (score 0):

It is required to write Group By if you use aggregate function.

```
SELECT sum(traveledDistanceInKm) actualDistanceInKm -sum(traveledDistanceInKm) 
From tracking_details
GROUP BY ....
```